# Turning a jade plant into a tree

Tags: trees, pruning, jade

I started a jade plant from a cutting.  It is growing nicely but has three different branches.  How do I trim my plant to make it a tree?  Do I split the three branches and repot each to turn into a tree?

Comment: Can you add a  photo of the plant please?